# Decoding YouTube's error 500 page

Tags: youtube

This is YouTube's 500 page. Can anyone help decode this information?

```
<p>500 Internal Server Error<p>

Sorry, something went wrong.
<p>A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation.<p>

If you see them, show them this information:
AB38WENgKfeJmWntJ8Y0Ckbfab0Fl4qsDIZv_fMhQIwCCsncG2kQVxdnam35
TrYeV6KqrEUJ4wyRq_JW8uFD_Tqp-jEO82tkDfwmnZwZUeIf1xBdHS_bYDi7
6Qh09C567MH_nUR0v93TVBYYKv9tHiJpRfbxMwXTUidN9m9q3sRoDI559_Uw
FVzGhjH5-Rd1GPLDrEkjcIaN_C3xZW80hy0VbJM3UI5EKohX35gZNK2aNi_8
Toi9z3L8lzpFTvz5GyHygFFBFEJpoRRJSu3CbH5S2OxXEVo4HgaaBTV7Dx_1
Zs1HZvPqhPIvXg9ifd4KZJiUJDFS8grPLE7bypFsRamyZw-OCVyUHsGQKBwu
77pTtRwpF3hOxYLxM4KnAyiY1N6yrASSWyaeumRDENAoEEe8i8MRxzifqHuR
leatvNMiwsg1pbSl7IIiaKljZaD9UkRms4Kvz1uYUNk4AwXnJ9-Wq44ufMPl
syiHp_LwaeqyuxXykJMl-SA9p05VrJc4kCETUW3Ybp0yTYvVrqggo56A0ofC
OiyAmifQA9pdYVGeumrQtbFlFyDyG9VKNpzn5lqutxFZPsS8xjiILfF3bETD
H4aUb5fT4iERFsEL7S-ClsXiA4yAJdAcNH-OhGg9ipAaIxRRTOR5P1MYx6s6
-OrqgpT5VEaEx2hMpS1afaMd2_F21sxvcz2d8sCpEceHHSfsntTth6talYeD
4l63aUTbbCKV1lHxKWxdUjACFKRobeAvIpcJPcdHSN3CNQI-LlIWIx9jeyBU
tDcL6S6GpRG_Z2of9fmw0LHpVU5hKlQ3lCPd4pVP6J02yrsBi0S9OLoE9jmM
T2FfCvU1sWUCsrZu4-UPflXMyRnFK8aN8DYiwWWE8OvnLQ-LIaRDhjp29u9a
LT6Lh4KxEmWF5XeZTwrzJxtuDLVomxVD5mpwFvK0YSoaz9dnPGXb0Fm2txSL
BvGssSrWBJ4FeR6eEEkd_UkQ-aUnPv2W-POox17n54wzTwLugYjslRenMzmk
I4_jlXcx9NpKmUg7Pa0qJuaElt-ZymPv6h0cXRUlyZtS0iT9-CQOHWLYMi3I
kKrYa6bKUCAj058JEderSnbXqGEMvwBeZ_xgJpAjJiSgMOxJPokhbS6ezIv4
1JNr_dvQyvu4vh-YQNZ37fNTqQcoDZtYflBsJjuGrJlmIcqBYufB9g6nUaOE
xPAKjPdvZ_z1Rn_8sWVf8NHNBBKGe5lgDgBxypsV0kIwVa9QOlehivOaieBI
tmqHNdQIfdob0XUTEBPSeLj9hmw3Bqplc3gqUfFhIvpHml6dOTbjBhfkq0TE
5yCRHL2VSe2Xt9_i8SPQA2yCtJVO8HP6pnohmxqlBWSTE8Xj87PI6quX7f9i
0W6PdtkMYaGJsd_Ly_4Ag-KmGNHN585tF9eC5HeQ8Gz-vHZWOUiM4OQAG9UA
31ENOAjHtYb--ketbUcdX_FdjGiPtI_GxYeBqEShICotcd-S-E3bEGO-77M2
CuUUdB1AUYVDZR81XejVG5kSWsrz-p1qZ-6sSpSHCp114C6PheQPCwRHEr_1
AS-DkZfIuZ-w8XAo6pHIwvnv0dORSo-hPFgw1rw2VE4aKsgeMc7ZoPUxby1d
Zr-o-0X4ZMgxoQHw_Ub27rTTHxS5Czt_vgBPq7k5OK5dm6b7JCs6Dbn2dsIA
AakPL26t4smr8IiPAnqNC2sn7vxSiAe9mTJ670eNc6C9dCSGwqzqSURiLHmT
kFyLhNSOdipttECmSSA1qh_E0K4LUhiOq7MFDEzg9CLD8kuJrqpEGgltYpD-
8lk7KEpyjMqbWFs-qeD8uJpsVfY2ac1C67OmyGzkERVoC245-YXuNCP8KUZH
LGzRm9jXwUP_piDETX0N5xj34VOCfUTffT1WlWHmB9WRPhwjIsYYy_kgR-uT
kIEDQ23NVUEGgDoryl-ymysIfwifjq-lPB3e85dz1PajNxawsCrKNeR_4hhq
zE_E4ete1EgXeAYoeH4UIgrPGXDD-KfoNoB6viNs0GzNU9czD9Avr-tDtARO
HBLSLIVRYq8caMA-jvpplTOMoDdmUMUWytf4Y_F5tKTpNtLPaAe1py1IgZBl
lfAGY9L_k5slelh_9gUBEkURxS2oMGf2gdSeDdRBxKKx5tF1b-cuMLK6JYZJ
vbGFYSsSENOkHrHEo9NdTwTi7NON9ZgRJgh7OaENK4TFCXrhKc4C6cyJs-V_
HZ0Q-B8XDyjL0qudg_0rJbjTNpNZajT_1WGsnhsTTAgMCGtTsj1T8vNx2LuX
lPQV30nUKpukdCP3zuiE9_aeJQ-nzf3dMQ-KnZU5APmGcIP_u2be6blieMWH
qVax1asKmuIjslh49ceM6lRt3Ia2bHUB8b1TMSjU4I79KPqc3clDnD8quNnU
cRkgfJ_8LCEoH7jml_2TNV0fLuH_9IOXF3jKjhT9K5f-e5N06GmPQLzdqzeQ
MnEtHuDcf4IizyKnB5GUXoNfQxbScQEzztQ_nHMYfF-E8KqoxxlK-Z0wfEDv
dJpL3mcNfFu_vz-_LJ0oI4dE0-vthsxbpTxVQkdI0E5XSi4nYfLqhXompk4j
gpxcHBjsXVbWcnelWhhQP15gCApj6Gz_ddRtk_uxiyiqZ44oUUDcl1KeWMTf
yhKDj7jgGNzTOkUsXZRPb9M77-ZYPuL2wR68E3b9PC_mS6HBHiUxQ7pXvkwS
Bi2CoFgd9SqBXk2O5I_BPaEoA8Aorazw4OvDrmTQrCk4OkGPKRukE4Ci2RMq
TZIYbBz-v3QxmOKHJoMXPNOfj93TRWpmlAd6iHCH6BVlSdfgfjdbHeD0b0ct
qXC_-S5fr1XFBuaZwaUTrBPxU-3IxWLp-dx7wpKcFykqKnByYpkzR3twKEXc
z--CZV79Qk3ZTMY9ATia4HbyhoAqY_hV9GKAHQdU_C-9qwYt0rliNUcizlBc
RHcwzoMyx30ciwbE8e9QsEH_AMa3E2ezuhjTqQlAG33_Gy5Bwe7fj6zNR0ud
jjpcNVf-wprWHEYxMcKwjCQvEHBtv6TnCHkgi_AOtPzzm3aYkMc_ysdNAnI7
DE_T9S5Mkcs6VdT2DWgUN_UC-oAw27xej0aTIn0GckXPDcLBgvrUhUPU3FRn
lW65syvFvxFmBOiCAEHD1q6Is1XhIf8vE6y0FMdNEWSMUW5rQG8f3KP_pjqG
XlUHnGrQPQysylrczHOj4E3WTT918xg2vrXVraDJbCYnJpaWp8m94iqZw2gJ
I_0UWOAZJMCYWz5jYf2DanCOBaGeZIO-UsWorP6YV3yHehirZ_Lc6KtaUorb
bm_BnnCqGVZypL4k6cDy-4GyO2GNohXzN-VWqbAIUQIat9w6RsDpzpS2DIap
96aMBDg24D73RhFTEgCSunPpbbGrDVU3GFkuTGFFBQWNfAU_F22XtoPr_ZB0
1zZPrBVXrEhebvrzp0Z31_sIT8zLop_oaSRvykbyJKKxucARfPee-d0xlgWN
WwKKtl49WVMhhu0OfDScH3knAVdv0LDAyt1fo3WF8jxdp7J9Hn3OWF3rcn0p
zw0gt6YV_6FRy_UbZmpLBvEhZQKUfKuxp6LK-SfHOilT29ERg9LJZhnyluTV
HELRtkJIcHzvphXupCIaIgZispYxHNSmAfze2cshWBYizGTBSKXWgrJeo7Q6
kEjim72yKaJ8JaLzMQFPxtQxhtvHRw94dCuXcajg3nE_r_9t7D8RicqF-CVV
tvp-rHMPhhizlgfixHWXrPB7reTtftT64pOSl5vUop8gTlbeW5Kg7WQAPNfp
zUH8YcAo0xDLJHA-FgTM4mYGih41rKaKKteWRFGU-fIyEzeO1s35tbGzlZ7R
btUG_fCpIbaJmucMZK9OzVBSfBgTBtFSesqKq6hIc8HctGcj5LPUfP9DRqqe
CrBi6bPjTlzrjaxJoU6oRq4ZtiBG38skOAaCUk61tpjilkq1fmWe2ByvLXhp
O2furZoiwNrizYmUmAW3ak3iSneScA64M-9apdZwhhEgpqyw5mUMYNT5SOOf
xZePlgXxhlL81t3KlofdbzT0w6tlbbT0NSbj9Q_zNkeZ8ar5aeMgTR-pJACg
baB20YVezziX-yboCF-uIptCTFNV
```

(Source: [this post on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7210750))

Comment: Looks like a hashed load of something - basically, you can't likely decode it! Unless you are indeed a well-educated nonhuman primate mammal (with the exception usually of the lemurs and tarsiers of course)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The debug information contained in the (urlsafe-)base64 blob is likely encrypted.

Think about it from Google's perspective: You would want to display a stack trace, relevant headers of the http request and possibly some internal state of the user session to help a developer debug the situation. On the other hand all that information might contain sensitive information that you don't want the general public to see or that might endanger the user if he copy'n pastes it in a public support forum.

If I was to take a guess of the format I would imagine:

- A public identifier of the key used for encryption (their servers could use different keys then)
- The debug data encrypted using an authenticated encryption scheme
- Additional data for error correction when [OCR has to be used](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7211569)

For statistical analysis of the format it would be interesting to sample a lot of these error messages and see if some parts of the message are less random than you would expect from encrypted data (symmetrical encrypted data should follow a uniform distribution).

Comment: Why would they send it to the user and not via an in-house message system? It is more likely to be a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem

Comment: @Karussell: Because they have an open TCP connection anyway. I actually have seen error message from Google stating that they are already being alerted as I see the error page, but maybe such an reporting avenue was not open in the case of the HTTP 500 error in question.

Comment: @Perseids but as the error message does not contain any instructions on how to contact Google - how would that be useful?

Comment: Plenty of people find ways to contact Google with these messages. (The most common way is the YouTube product forums; I also see them on reddit often.) They're useful because they contain enough information, in most cases, to directly identify *which* problem the user is having (even long after alerts are no longer going on). If there wasn't a way for users to share this info, if they reached out, we wouldn't be able to say if their specific problem was fixed.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you are not the only one who is looking for some secret messages in YouTube error page. It seems that you can decode it using Base64.

Here is how:

http://www.cambus.net/decoding-youtube-http-error-500-message/

In a nutshell:

> Sadly, contrary to my expectations, there doesn't seem to be any
>   hidden message… Screw you, highly trained monkeys!

I guess it is just another Easter Egg similar to 'Goats Teleported' performance counter Google Chrome had:

https://plus.google.com/+RobertPitt/posts/PrqAX3kVapn

But I guess unless you look like this, you can't be 100% sure.
[image: OMG Monkeys!]

Comment: A highly trained monkey works at google, and me not? This is depressing, man.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible that this is random padding to avoid the "friendly" IE error pages that show if your error page does not contain more than 512 bytes of HTML.  It would be base64 encoded if it were simply random bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Imho this is all about customer care.

Actually there would be no need to send the error/debug message to the customer, because, I guess, it's already handled internally.

So:

- why do we see this?
- and why do they crypt it?
- and is there really no hidden message for us?

Although the error might be handled and resolved internally, this does not necessarily satisfy a customer, who is not able to use the product. They pretty much do crypt by a good reason as this debug message might reveal more than a typical admin is used to.
And also there is no need to hide a message for us. Why? Because we NEVER stop until we find something.

I think:

- internally the error is dealt with
- external users might have something in hand to tell a technician if necessary and in return can get an approximation of ongoing problem

All in all nothing special about it and i think linking e.g. to the inf. monkey theorem is a bit overspectulated...

Comment: The reason it gets printed out to the client is in cases where the failure is at such a low level that it cannot be logged (e.g. if there's a bug in the logging code itself).

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means google has a problem which can not resolve. So when reporting a bug the most important thing is to prepare reproduction steps. So I tried to find an answer of the question "When this happens?"

I found this post in reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/40k858/is_youtube_giving_you_500_internal_server_errors/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_list

As resume:

- It happens on desktops (www...), it works ok on mobile version (m...)
- It happens for authenticated users. For anonymous users is working fine.
- The problem is resolved after cookies are cleaned.

So I would give a direction: try to find the key in the session cookie. I hope my 2 cents will help.