# What is the meaning of the text in youtube 500 internal error

Tags: youtube, http-error

I am sorry if this doesn't belong here but I dont know where it does.
I tried to play a youtube video and got an http 500 error with the following text:

> Sorry, 
>   something went wrong. 
>   A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation. If you see them, send them
>   this information as text (screenshots frighten them):
>   **> AB38WEMQgYMwAsSndv0qRVwB2h6TTDLZbomJEWU6qMCSOlXSieCCjveU
>   7hDWK8oeERuik9Fw-jLjNczrdngnBDUZpExmTWm6BdtwUW26ecXKhmYi
>   NnZ91eCdo8ejZ5bzzhv9pYvCPlTDFN6vq6pHgGMqBsfH7EMrHYFjlwq_
>   7yWIObcAM2Ni1tTP1fR8EkhGYIwD1gpYuNLBnVT-imW3RBgFijeA8iLA
>   v0TEZ_HkJP7rRGS0txolsJEP_vMnhJZKdEd3VP1zfhoB6Vl_cUhtr69
>   yB6be9FMd6kRpnSiItgbxPvyrFa75aJlkBe0H72CdAXeRifbGaDc1_q2
>   44Tms5HH6dfasPa9kVkzhy3GkpTbXZGIPRynzhRdrb0R8uMv-Y7kyhC6
>   JgEAQoe5zld02-rlMu6DpN6fFtkGWZ3Lt-e-hECLRuYqHX-eCW567f8c
>   mmxd8YEGRS4qURfh4eFl1uvQ_b0rEOZTHrkzUNlTLbSIW6FesFccjX83
>   ybB5fP-21S60JudEj1ZzM6m50GPFTV8gRFDz5r7-cFR1uMkKfnq1U0FC
>   b1Tehcova6OabgROHDljpM3J8jJlLEmQKqxOSugMzmelDZLVw30pMyjb
>   Wm4U4fin2J4sTIN9AYFo-aGzmv4JvbSURzKGamVPXt2R6v2PvB5SPeBb
>   yJ8oVAv5j34bClZksFlShm5xTCUEAB3q9FfoUSvqqT6pOOoeHqFEmiGl
>   ggJcl79sAFfjSVeSRpU5qjJ4np7ve3-jImsQNLO7lCC-FDq3Ao8peKPc
>   wVQDNTXcXXTSpMkk5mWJG4LRgaVQG4mFg-gcRTphCK_hWeFsoEgrdX_D
>   j_bdM13tBeQFFv8lIXNcMX6bME36U8PaBWCMjGBlhZVpZ9vArH0vehC0
>   FO5SPxWJsAjCJU1XY2f6AMPQioQS9h2OOZA6p6EFmGFNw-d5jeqvLIfx
>   Cp3BHa_cddgBHQabZI77Db62hSoAzI-8FrJWy9dDTWjuj_MntCZcfUNY
>   URSrXvXsiKRaz_5sJ-S2rSX2aCxJSne_gsgT1Y-YIzO1xBD9wuLts20G
>   4YX2Scpyj8mui7I8bn_Sx6H3iyFMrEVJwhneCKbeaXMiIOk6CiJNgS3s
>   jdcLUB_Nv5tR35j8BvAbW5ZgNT57SKp9SDFDdTZyDfJ0Eg9aCjxARVBc
>   T4V6Hs_c31yZ5SDnu0e9drBS5ynf_ZydZAJR9AEiEAQfzayUjJgy9NCB
>   viA0_EPY2dVPOlW3VWJ7C5HhKksSXeWQ45fE0IS1WOwOlq50yvKF0SoB
>   asoT4ziflWe92IA56Ds3_XXeWMBwcOjXIb2KCkqE_hdChOyZpiufLB4t
>   Ngl5WAglVNfV1Z45omJv4MGiBgUcpICvYmkJ_OcTVi03BbS9cuXlBbE7
>   ivuqu1AfHPnKp8RBGpY_mKpLrYKYhJ5faXi2INdZ-9xh6MAqehN6cKQj
>   SgweGtclPuX0teQye3h8P5vp425ARfQEzbFYmRULRQiITz16az-JgVmP
>   Di3XaE4Qq7rFpumWPuuHGqlTjmurFIuh0SZ2sklMxPQFGOYIEjNNsEtE
>   UPuL0DApAqnP1AH3mHMqHKzdgzFvg7k9Z86M5yt4CDatYmjktsuNzdBJ
>   wArAWFRfr86x7XBdkr9eVa8Hp-6x86CzR38nypBBddU2Jr4E8RsG8-7h
>   iCvxlHwRoPXoGouIXflUIe5mHZveEAtQGYZzeJKFvZ8YojTLLx8bKFgu
>   zsJ0Cll3bWmHZS5ZPHzppuvZauwaVKFxLX0EjjdMOiFaueno1pXfp4jm
>   3QqdllBQSzai4Z2wXfhU9Ql_cFzqpzfPMBNxt6mge-0ARsMsEeR5PDF
>   2wNglV05GkaVp4JgWSTo7lQ3OnJKQNmECTGaYNbGR7IsGigTMc3QM0iH
>   9ueR3-l75e3YYMlRl9tZWquJd54eGh5vYTLrbW60CrBZQLSKpxqpxX_W
>   9x_aaEhESZSXVx0**

Do you know the meaning of the text? I have a feeling it has something special about it because when I google search for it I get an error 400:
[image]

any one know? thanks

Comment: This has already been addressed here: [decoding-youtubes-error-500-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681084/decoding-youtubes-error-500-page), and judging by answers there, there is no information in this error message that you could use.